# Infinite scroll script not working on tagged pages? [ Masonry ]

Tags: blogs, tumblr, jquery-masonry, infinite-scroll

So, basically, I'm working on my first Tumblr theme here: teenaqe-vow.tumblr.com and everything is fine and dandy so far EXCEPT for  the infinite scroll code. What happens is it works perfectly fine until you go to a tagged page like this one.  http://teenaqe-vow.tumblr.com/tagged/music  What happens is that when you scroll down, instead of loading the next page of the tagged pages, it loads a page from the index page. I'm using a script that keeps the posts all nestled together and renders the infinite scroll and without it there are gaps in the posts and it doesn't work out too well.

I'm really new with this whole thing so I'm kind of at a loss of how to fix it. I apologize if any of the information I provide is inadequate, please let me know if you need something more from me.

Here is the entire theme code: http://pastebin.com/X8DaLKPG

Here is the infinite scroll / masonry part:

```
{block:IndexPage}{block:IfTwoColumn}
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

{block:IfInfiniteScroll}
<div id="pagination"><a href="/page/2"></a></div>
<script src="http://static.tumblr.com/6hsqxdt/vmwm2rb4g/infinitescrolling.js"></script>
{/block:IfInfiniteScroll}

<script src="http://static.tumblr.com/6hsqxdt/QBym35odk/jquery.masonry.js"></script>

<script>
$(function(){
var $container = $('#content');
$container.imagesLoaded(function(){
$container.masonry({
itemSelector: '#entry',
});
});
$container.infinitescroll({
itemSelector : "#entry",
navSelector : "#pagination",
nextSelector : "#pagination a",
loadingImg : "http://media.tumblr.com/ec1742dbca16ca94b47814f1de4e37e6/tumblr_inline_mj8pf7Te3l1qz4rgp.png",
loadingText : "<em></em>",
bufferPx : 10000,
extraScrollPx: 12000,
},
// trigger Masonry as a callback
function( newElements ) {
  var $newElems = $( newElements ).css({ opacity: 0 });
// ensure that images load before adding to masonry layout
$newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
$newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
$container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true );
});
}
);
});
</script>
{/block:IfTwoColumn}{/block:IndexPage}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pagination link is fixed on the main page (it always points to `user.tumblr.com/page/2/`). Use the Tumblr API pagination tools instead.

Answer (score 0):

I have been having this same issue on my Tumblr and have finally resolved it, so I thought that I would share my mistake and my resolution in the hopes that it will help a fellow beginner, such as myself :)

This is what I had to start with that was causing the issue:

```
<div class="pagination"><span id="page_nav"><span onclick='return false;'><a style="float:right;opacity:1;" href="/page/2" id="next"></a></div>
```

And this is my resolution:

```
<div class="pagination"><span id="page_nav"><span onclick='return false;'><a style="float:right;opacity:1;" {block:NextPage}href={NextPage} id="next" {/block:NextPage}></a></div>
```

You'll notice that the only change has been made to the href attribute. When you set it to /page/2, it's telling the tag page to show page 2 from the index page, because it is missing the name of the tag from the URL. When you add Tumblr's pagination block tag for next page ({block:NextPage}) and the next page URL ({NextPage}), it will then be able to decipher whether or not you are starting from an index page or a tag page, and then be able to fill in the blanks in the URL by itself. I hope this helps!